# Using OData with POCO

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, odata

Is it possible to use OData with POCO or is it limited to just LinqToEntities?

All the examples I can find only seem to use the Entity Framework.

Also is the seen as a replacement to WCF Services or is it intended to run in parallel?

Thanks